# How do developer's guarantee safe database operations in asynchronous environments?

Tags: node.js, express, http

I am in the process of building an API service using Node.js with ExpressJS. I understand Node is single threaded, but allows for asynchronous operations.

For example, this simple express route:

```
app.post('/a', (req, res) => {
    console.log('processing');
    setTimeout(() => {
        res.send('Hello World!');
        console.log('sent');
    }, 5000);
    console.log('waiting');
});
```

If I make 2 immediately consecutive requests to this route, the console logs are run in parallel. What if these were writes to a database instead of setTimeout's? How do developers guarantee synchronous writes, so that if this endpoint was pinged twice immediately, it would not result in duplicate inserts for example? Is it controlled on the database side (with indexes, perhaps)? Maybe with transactions, but what if the database doesn't support transactions?

Any help or understanding would be more than appreciated.

Comment: *Is it controlled on the database side* Yes, but there's also hopefully frontend code that prevents immediate resubmission to the same endpoint

Comment: @CertainPerformance, yes, I forgot to mention this question was strictly for server side context. Thank you!